# Django distinct method()

Tags: django, django-views

For every selection box ID shown in my HTML must be represent to my StudentsCoreValuesDescription , my problem is some of the ID in StudentsCoreValuesDescription didn't print in selection box

I have this query in my views.py

```
me = StudentsCoreValuesDescription.objects.filter(grading_Period = coreperiod)\
        .values('id','Marking','Students_Enrollment_Records').distinct('Students_Enrollment_Records')
            .order_by('Students_Enrollment_Records')
```

this is the result

[image]

I just want that for every selection box, the display must be different **ID**'s,

To understand more, 
Please take a look to my admin site, and check the ID, the ID must be unique in the selection Box and the same as the admin site, to function properly when I update the data

[image]

its looks like it only loop the result of distinct Student name

this is my html

```
{% for students in me %}

    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="names"><input type="hidden" value="{{students.id}}" name="student">{{students.Students_Enrollment_Records}}</td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <select name="marking" >

                <option value="{{students.Marking.id}}" >{{students.id}}</option>
                {% for m in marking %}
                    <option value="{{m.Marking}}" >{{m.Marking}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <select  name="marking">
                <option value="{{students.Marking.id}}" >{{students.id}}</option>
                {% for m in marking %}
                    <option value="{{m.Marking}}">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <select  name="marking">
                <option value="{{students.Marking.id}}" >{{students.id}}</option>
                {% for m in marking %}
                    <option value="{{m.Marking}}">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <select  name="marking">
                <option value="{{students.Marking.id}}" >{{students.id}}</option>
                {% for m in marking %}
                    <option value="{{m.Marking}}">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <select name="marking">
                <option value="{{students.Marking.id}}" >{{students.id}}</option>
                {% for m in marking %}
                    <option value="{{m.Marking}}">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <select name="marking">
                <option value="{{students.Marking.id}}" >{{students.id}}</option>
                {% for m in marking %}
                    <option value="{{m.Marking}}">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <select name="marking">
                <option value="{{students.Marking.id}}" >{{students.id}}</option>
                {% for m in marking %}
                    <option value="{{m.Marking}}">{{m.Marking}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

this is my models

```
class StudentsCoreValuesDescription(models.Model):
    Teacher = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                null=True, blank=True)
    Core_Values = models.ForeignKey(CoreValuesDescription,
                                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Marking =  models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True,blank=True)

    Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentPeriodSummary, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    GradeLevel = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel,on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   null=True, blank=True)
    Sections = models.ForeignKey(Section,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    grading_Period = models.ForeignKey(gradingPeriod,on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                       null=True, blank=True)
    remarks =  models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
```

please help me guys

Comment: It looks that way as it is. Look at your template. You iterate over the queryset which is grouped by Students_Enrollment_Records. Then for each of the columns you are creating the same select list where the first entry is the same, the result of ```students.Marketing.id``` then  you iterate over another queryset (I assume) to populate other options.  So it's working as you have designed gut I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve. What are the values you wish to have in each select input for each student?

Comment: I just want that for every selection box has unique ID, like in my admin site,

Comment: it must be unique ID per selection box to update selection boxes, in my case the only updating is 929, ,940, 957, 936, 943 ID's @SteveMapes

Comment: What is the `marking` collection? How should that relate to the current `students` per row when iterating over `me`?

Comment: I'm still not really following. Each box won't be unique as the code in the template uses the same value for each column within each row.  Or are you asking why you have missing rows as that would be due to the query not returning results for the other students.  Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "unique ID per selection box to update selection boxes"

Comment: @schillingt marking is a charfield, I print it to ID in HTML to trace why it some selection box didn't update, for every selection box in my HTML MUST BE represent the ID of my StudentsCoreValuesDescription model, please check the picture of my admin site

Comment: @SteveMapes for every selection box shown in my HTML must be represent the ID of StudentsCoreValuesDescription please check my admin site picture